# How I can read content from file line by line in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, plugins, flutter-web

I need your help with this please, I am uploading a TXT file with plugin **file_picker** in Flutter WEB and it is works, after that I would like to read the content line by line and process this data, but I dont know to do this...

My code is this:

```
  //load File from txt
  loadFile() async {
    FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['txt'],
    );

    if (result != null) {
      PlatformFile file = result.files.first;

      print(file.name);
      // print(file.bytes);
      print(file.size);
      print(file.extension);
      print(file.path);

      print("contenido");

      setState(() {
        _nameFile = file.name;
        _uploadFile = true;
      });
    } 
  }
```

Someone has any idea to do this?, I was investigating but I did not find much information about it, thnx a lot for that

PD: this project is only works on FLutter Web

Comment: `file.readStream
.map(utf8.decode)
.transform(LineSplitter())
.listen((line) => print('line: $line'));`

Comment: I used this way, but I got an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: you did not use `withReadStream: true` when calling `pickFiles`

Comment: and? still `null`?

Comment: @pskink no, Now it works fine, thnx a lot!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the `file.bytes` to a `String` and then split this `String` at each line return (`\n`) the following way:

```dart
import 'convert.dart';

String fileContent = utf8.decode(file.bytes);
List<String> lines = fileContent.split('\n');
```